# Не знаю как верстать календарь

Tags: html, css

Помогите. Не могу верстать этот участок, не знаю... это либо слайдером сделать либо календарем, хочу узнать ответ и решения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

http://s012.radikal.ru/i320/1702/95/afa8e9404034.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте таймлайн плагин на JS
например: 
http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Dynamic-Scrolling-Timeline-Plugin-jQuery-jTLine.html
вот демо
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Dynamic-Scrolling-Timeline-Plugin-jQuery-jTLine/

Ещё замечательный таймлайнер:
http://www.csslab.cl/2011/08/18/jquery-timelinr/ (http://www.csslab.cl/ejemplos/timelinr/latest/horizontal.html)- пример

Comment: Спасибо большое!! обязательно попробую